# How to automate Dotfuscator in build

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dll, dotfuscator

I have to protect some dll in my mvc2 project in visual studio 2010. I'm using Dotfuscator and i want to automate it in build process. I refer the following article but I have no idea how to implement it. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082%28v=vs.107%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this by creating a .proj file (MSBuild.exe) and call it directly using exec.

```
<Exec Command='"$(OBFU_HOME)\dotfuscator.exe" dotfuscator.xml'/>
<Exec Command='"$(SN_HOME)\sn.exe" -R filename.dll filename.snk'/>
```

OBFU_HOME & SN_HOME are set in the environment. Make sure you call sn.exe after as the dll needs to be re-signed.

Will this work for you? If not, then you need to put it in the post build event handler.

Comment: I'am new to .Net development. I checked the .csproj file. But i have no idea how to this. where should i enter those lines. Could you please explain. thankyou.

Comment: Here you go - an intro to creating a .proj file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479(v=vs.80).aspx